# How to 3D plot matrices that are not squared in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, heatmap, kernel-density

I would like to plot a heatmap using my own mathematical function instead of the Kernel density estimation. But for the moment my problem comes from the fact that I cannot 3D plot this function using `persp()` if my `x` & `y` axes are not squared. Indeed the heatmap is sized 855 x 670.

1) Is there a way to solve this problem?

2) Plus, does anyone know how to turn this into a heatmap?

Thanks in advance. Please, find a part of my script below.

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Here are two functions we will need:

```
rep.row <- function(x, n){
  matrix(rep(x, each = n), nrow = n)
}
rep.col <- function(x, n){
  matrix(rep(x, each = n), ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

This reads an image and extracts its dimensions (i.e., width and length):

```
require('png')
png <- readPNG("myImage.png")
res <- dim(png)[2:1]
```

For information:

```
> dim(png)[2:1]
[1] 855 670
```

These are fixed parameters:

```
alphaW <- 53
alphaH <- 31
a <- 2.3
```

I create two vectors (i.e., `e1` and `e2`) based on the image dimensions. Therefore, `e1` is 855-cells long and `e2` is 670-cells long. Then I use the functions above in order to create two matrices (i.e., `E1` and `E2`) the same size of the image (i.e., 855 x 670).

```
e1 <- seq(-alphaW, alphaW, length = res[1])
e2 <- seq(-alphaH, alphaH, length = res[2])

E1 <- rep.row(e1, res[2])
E2 <- rep.col(e2, res[1])
```

A computation of these two matrices is used to create a 3rd matrix, `SV`:

```
SV <- sqrt((a / (a + ((E1^2) + (E2^2)))))
```

Finally I want to plot a 3D representation of this matrix:

```
persp(x = e1, y = e2, z = SV,
      col = "lightgoldenrod",
      border = NA,
      theta = 30,
      phi = 15,
      ticktype = "detailed",
      ltheta = -120,
      shade = 0.25)
```

This should output something like {[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iHLF.png)}, however, I receive:

```
Error in persp.default(e1, e2, SV, col = "lightgoldenrod", border = NA,  :
argument 'z' incorrect
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that doesn't require image files we don't have access to.

Comment: Any .png file would have been ok actually. But I completely understand the problem issued from the fact that you cannot just copy/paste and compute. My bad. My problem is solved though. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched x and y. If you look at the help page for persp(), you will notice that x should have length nrow(z) and y length ncol(z). So although intuitively you might expect rows to be on the vertical axis (how you visualise the matrix), it seems to be the other way around.

This works:

```
persp(y = e1, x = e2, z = SV,
      col = "lightgoldenrod",
      border = NA,
      theta = 30,
      phi = 15,
      ticktype = "detailed",
      ltheta = -120,
      shade = 0.25)
```

Comment: Well… That was simple. Thanks a lot!